# How to refer UICollectionView from UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Can I refer UICollectionView from UICollectionViewCell?
I finally want to refer ViewController from UICollectionViewCell.

Following codes are in my CustomCollectionViewCell Class.
I want to archive tweet support in this class.

```
@IBAction func tweetBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let cvc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    if let c = cvc {
        c.setInitialText("test tweet from iOS App")

        ### How can I refer ViewController??
        viewController = ???????

        if let vc = viewController {
            vc.present(c, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the code sample or what you are trying to achieve. What I understand is that you want some action back in your view controller when you perform some action on your cell. Am I correct?

So As per the comments, Custom collection view cell :

class CustomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBAction func tweetButtonPressed() {

    let cvc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    if let c = cvc {
        c.setInitialText("test tweet from iOS App")

        self.parentViewController?.presentViewController(c, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

}

Create a Extension.Swift file :

import UIKit

extension UIView {

```
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {

    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self

    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()

        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {

            return viewController

        }

    }

    return nil

}
```

}

This is working for me. All the best!

Comment: You could either use delegation. So, when you tap on a button inside your cell, you could delegate back to your view controller and then present your social VC. or You could also create an extension on UIVIew to get parent controller and then use it inside your custom cell class and then present View controller. I personally would do it using Delegation Because a cell should not be having the code for presenting the new controller I feel But I am posting the solution using extension for you.

Comment: So this is my collectionview cell class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I also thought that a cell should not have the codes for presenting a ViewController.
I decided to do it using delegation method!!